# Rails 4 -Ajax create Events in Fullcalendar in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to integrate the fullcalendar gem in one of my apps, and i would link to drag the mouse over two dates and show a popup where the user write the information abou the event and via ajax (without reloading the page) the event would be created in the database and appear in the calendar.

Right now i have the calendar showing the Events that i create manually but when i drag the mousse over to dates, it shows the popup for input the fields and it shows the event in the calendar, but when i refresh the page the event disappear, meaning that the event is not being saved in the database. This is my code:

**index.json.builder**

```
json.array!(@events) do |event|
  json.extract! event, :id, :title, :description
  json.start event.start_time
  json.end event.end_time
  json.url event_url(event, format: :html)
end
```

**events/index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Events</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Start time</th>
      <th>End time</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= event.title %></td>
        <td><%= event.description %></td>
        <td><%= event.start_time %></td>
        <td><%= event.end_time %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', event %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Event', new_event_path %>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

**events_controller**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /events/new
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end

  # GET /events/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /events
  # POST /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /events/1
  # PATCH/PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /events/1
  # DELETE /events/1.json
  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :start_time, :end_time)
    end
end
```

**events.coffee**

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar(
    events: '/events.json'
    selectable: true
    selectHelper: true
    select: (start, end) ->
      title = prompt("Event Title:")
      description = prompt("Event Description:")
      eventData = undefined
      if title && description
        eventData =
          title: title
          description: description
          start: start
          end: end
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar "renderEvent", eventData, true # stick? = true
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar "unselect"
  )
  $.ajax
  url: 'events'
  type: 'POST'
  data: eventData
  dataType: 'json'
  success: (json) ->
    alert json.msg
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar 'renderEvent', eventData, true
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar 'refetchEvents'
    return
```

The event model doesn't have any code.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks and best regards to all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the time format probably just like here (this is for update but should be the same for creation)

```
eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
    return updateEvent(event);
}, 
eventResize: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {
    return updateEvent(event);
},

updateEvent = function(the_event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: "/users/" + currentUserId + "/events/" + the_event.id,
    data: { event: {
      title: the_event.title,
      start_at: "" + new Date(the_event.start).toUTCString(),
      end_at: "" + new Date(the_event.end).toUTCString(),
      body: the_event.body || "",
      sender_id: the_event.senderId,
      recipient_id: the_event.recipientId,
      all_day: the_event.allDay }
    }
  });
};
```